# Golang DynamoDB and array of object trying to filter 1 element

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

in go I tried following code:

```
queryInput := &dynamodb.QueryInput{
    TableName:              &db.TableName,
    KeyConditionExpression: aws.String("#Type = :typeVal"),
    ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]string{
        "#Type":     "Type",
        "#Active":   "Active",
        "#Contents": "Contents",
        "#Language": lang, // Assuming lang is the desired language key
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        ":typeVal":   &dynamodb.AttributeValue{S: aws.String(entityType)},
        ":activeVal": &dynamodb.AttributeValue{BOOL: aws.Bool(true)},
    },
    FilterExpression:   aws.String("#Active = :activeVal"),
    ProjectionExpression: aws.String("#Contents.#Language"),
}
```

where Contents in DynamoDB table is:

```
{
  "DE": {
    "S": "123 qwe."
  },
  "EN": {
    "S": "asd 678"
  }
}
```

in Go its a map[string]string, but I can not make it working.
What I need is to query by Type and Active but as a Contents columnd from DB get filetered array with just 1 element matching language criteria

can someone help me ? I think its possible in Mongo but not sure if in DynamoDB I can do this.